# how to add total cost based on the item selected from different tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

i have two tabs, one shows some hotel names from one location and other tab shows some hotels from another location.

and when i select one hotel from one tab and then another from another tab. the total should be hotel_location1 + hotel_location2.

here is my code:

for tabs:

```html
<div class="tabs-x tabs-left">
<ul id="myTab-kv-13" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="active"><a href="#hotel-pb" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Port Blair</a></li>
<li><a href="#hotel-hl" role="tab-kv" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Havelock</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent-kv-13" class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="hotel-pb">
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
<div class="panel panel-red">
<div class="panel-heading">velocity</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<img src="images/hotels/velocity.png" class="img-responsive"/>
<div class="my-caption">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
<select name="hotel_cat" id="hotel_cat_1" class="form-control" onchange="hotel_rate()">
<option value="">Category</option>
<option value="Standard Rs: 2000">Standard Rs: 2000</option>
<option value="Deluxe Rs: 2200">Deluxe Rs: 2200</option>
<option value="Family Rs: 3000">Family Rs: 3000</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="sel_cat_1" id="sel_cat_1"/>
<br />
<button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" name="add_this_1" id="add_this_1" data-hname="velocity" data-elem="1" onclick="total_rate()">Select</button>
<input type="hidden" name="em_1" id="em_1" value="800"/>
<input type="hidden" name="s_tax_1" id="s_tax_1" value="8.4"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
<div class="panel panel-red">
<div class="panel-heading">White Coral</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<img src="images/hotels/White Coral.png" class="img-responsive"/>
<div class="my-caption">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
<select name="hotel_cat" id="hotel_cat_2" class="form-control" onchange="hotel_rate()">
<option value="">Category</option>
<option value="Dlx Lake View Rs: 4500">Dlx Lake View Rs: 4500</option>
<option value="Dlx Mountain View Rs: 4000">Dlx Mountain View Rs: 4000</option>
<option value="Std Lake View Rs: 3500">Std Lake View Rs: 3500</option>
<option value="Std Mountain View Rs: 3000">Std Mountain View Rs: 3000</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="sel_cat_2" id="sel_cat_2"/>
<br />
<button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" name="add_this_2" id="add_this_2" data-hname="White Coral" data-elem="2" onclick="total_rate()">Select</button>
<input type="hidden" name="em_2" id="em_2" value="800"/>
<input type="hidden" name="s_tax_2" id="s_tax_2" value="8.4"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<input  type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="3"/>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="hotel-hl">
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
<div class="panel panel-red">
<div class="panel-heading">blue bird resort</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<img src="images/hotels/blue bird resort.png" class="img-responsive"/>
<div class="my-caption">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
<select name="hotel_cat" id="hotel_cat" class="form-control" onchange="hotel_rate()">
<option value="">Category</option>
<option value="Standard Rs: 2000">Standard Rs: 2000</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="sel_cat_3" id="sel_cat_3"/>
<br />
<button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" name="add_this_3" id="add_this_3" data-hname="blue bird resort" data-elem="3" onclick="total_rate()">Select</button>
<input type="hidden" name="em_3" id="em_3" value="800"/>
<input type="hidden" name="s_tax_3" id="s_tax_3" value="8.4"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

scripts: for hotel_rate()

```js
function hotel_rate(){ // just define the function.
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     var i=1;
     var cnt = $("#count").val();
     for(i=1;i<cnt;i++){
   var cost_em = $("#em_"+i).val();
         var cat = $("#hotel_cat_"+i).val();
         var test = cat.split(':'); 
         var cat_cost = parseInt(test[1]);
         $("#sel_cat_"+i).val(cat_cost);
   $('.btn-active').removeClass('btn-success btn-active').addClass('btn-danger').html('Select');
    
  }
   
 });
 }
```

script: total_cost()

```js
function total_rate(){
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
   var button = $(event.target);
   $('.btn').removeClass('btn-success btn-active').addClass('btn-danger').html('Select');
  
   button.html('Selected');
   button.removeClass("btn-danger");
         button.addClass("btn-success btn-active");
   
    
   var elem = button.data('elem');
   var hname = button.data('hname');
    var s_tax = $("#s_tax_"+elem).val();
   var cost_em = $("#em_"+elem).val();
         var cat_cost = $("#sel_cat_"+elem).val();
   var rooms = $("#rooms").val();
   var per = $('#persons').val();
   var mattress = per - (rooms*2);
   var cost_hotel = parseInt((cat_cost * rooms) + (cost_em * mattress));
   var cost_hotel_final = parseInt(cost_hotel + (s_tax/100 * cost_hotel));
   $("#tot_hotel_cost").val(cost_hotel_final);
   $("#hotels").html(hname);
   total();
  });
 }
```

scripts: rest for adding all the datas.

```js
function total_transport(){
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   var trans_pb = $("#t_pb").val();
   var trans_hl = $("#t_hl").val();
   var trans_nl = $("#t_nl").val();
   var total_transportation_cost = trans_pb + trans_hl + trans_nl;
   $("#tot_transp").val(total_transportation_cost);
   total();
 });
 }
 function total(){
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   var tot_hotel_cost = $("#tot_hotel_cost").val();
   var tot_transp = $("#tot_transp").val();
   var total_final_cost = tot_transp + tot_hotel_cost;
   $("#total_cost").html(total_final_cost);
   
 });
 }
```

my error is i am not able to add the hotel rates based on different tabs i.e for different locations.

any type of help would be appreciated. thnx in advance.

Comment: Have you considered storing values in `localStorage` or passing it to next tab using `query Parameter`?

Comment: Per my understanding, tab means another html page. Right? If yes, when you are done calculations and you want to reroute, you can try `localStorage.setItem(propertyName, value)` and retrieve it on next page's load using `localStorage.getItem(propertyName)`

Comment: actually tabs not individual pages. its a single page where different tabs are present.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you can try 2 options.

- Use an object to store values.
- Fetch values from elements on the fly.

Following is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Us8uc/3893/) simulating both options.

#### Code

```js
// Global Object to store values.
// Update value on every stage.
var user = {
    firstName:'',
    lastName:'',
    age:''
}

function onTheFly(){
 var _fname = $("#txtFirstName").val();
    var _lname = $("#txtLastName").val();
    var _age = $("#txtAge").val();
    
    $("#lblOnTheFly").text(_fname + " " + _lname + " is " + _age + " years old.")
}

// Navigate UI
function next(id){
 $(".tab-content").slideUp();;
    $("#"+id).slideDown();
    
    switch(id){
        case "tab2":
            user.firstName = $("#txtFirstName").val();
            break;
            case "tab3":
            user.lastName = $("#txtLastName").val();
            break;
            case "tab4":
            user.age = $("#txtAge").val();
            $("#lblSummary").text(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName + " is " + user.age + "years old");
            break;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
padding: 20px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 1.5;
font-size: 14px;        
}

.tabs-menu {
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.tabs-menu li {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
    border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
    border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
}

.tabs-menu li.current {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    z-index: 5;
}

.tabs-menu li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

.tabs-menu .current a {
    color: #2e7da3;
}

.tab {
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: auto;
}

.tab-content {
    width: 660px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
}

#tab1 {
 display: block;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-container">
    <div class="tab">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">
            Enter First Name: <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" />
            <button onclick="next('tab2')">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
            Enter Last Name: <input type="text" id="txtLastName" />
            <button onclick="next('tab3')">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">
            Enter Age: <input type="text" id="txtAge" />
            <button onclick="next('tab4')">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab-content">
            <h1>Summary</h1>
            <p id="lblSummary"></p>
            
            <button onclick="onTheFly()">Generate Summary</button>
            <p id="lblOnTheFly"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorrt thats not i asked. but if u hv time then do have a look in http://exotictriplanner.com/test_video/honeymoon-package.php  and select the 1st one then select date and enter no. of persons then u can see accomodation tabs. refer that tabs which are inside accomodation tab.